# Angular get blog by id not displaying anything on browser

Tags: node.js, angular, routes

I'm building a blog application based on MEAN stack, using Angular in front-end, node in back-end and mongoDB for server. When I'm trying to access a particular blog by it's blogId, the browser is not showing anything. Although I'm getting the right data fetched from backend with a 304 status and the right blogId is also passing by the route. The console is also logging the right object. Below is my **blog-view.component.ts** file

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ToastrManager } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';

import { BlogService } from '../blog.service';
import { BlogHttpService } from '../blog-http.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-view',
  templateUrl: './blog-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-view.component.css'],
  providers: [Location]
})
export class BlogViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public currentBlog;

   constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public blogHttpService:BlogHttpService, public toastr: ToastrManager, private location: Location) { 
    console.log("view-blog constructor called")
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("view-blog ngOnInIt called");
    let myBlogId = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('blogId');
    console.log(myBlogId);
    this.currentBlog = this.blogHttpService.getSingleBlogInformation(myBlogId).subscribe(

                data =>{
                  console.log(data);
                  this.currentBlog = data["data"];
                  },

                error =>{
                  console.log("some error occured");
                  console.log(error.errorMessage);

                })


  }

  public deleteThisBlog(): any {
    this.blogHttpService.deleteBlog(this.currentBlog.blogId).subscribe(
      data =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.toastr.successToastr('This blog is successfully deleted.', 'Success!');
        setTimeout(() =>{
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }, 1000)

      },
      error =>{
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
        this.toastr.errorToastr('Some Error Occured.', 'Oops!');
      }
    )
  }

  public goBackToPreviousPage(): any {
    this.location.back();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("view-blog component destroyed");
  }

}
```

**blog-view.component.html**

```
  <div class="row" *ngIf="currentBlog" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>{{currentBlog.title}}</h2>
      <p>posted by {{currentBlog.author}} on {{currentBlog.created | date:'medium'}}</p>
      <p *ngIf="currentBlog.tags!=undefined && currentBlog.tags.length>0">tags : <span *ngFor="let tag of currentBlog.tags;let first=first;let last=last">{{tag}}{{last ? '' : ', '}}</span></p>
      <hr>
      <div [innerHtml]="currentBlog.bodyHtml"></div>
      <hr>
      <h5>category - {{currentBlog.category}}</h5>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" *ngIf="currentBlog">
      <div class="col-md-4">

      <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/edit',currentBlog.blogId]">Edit</a>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteThisBlog()">Delete</a>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goBackToPreviousPage()">Go Back</a>
      </div>
    </div>  

  </div>



</div>
```

**blog-http.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class BlogHttpService {

  public allBlogs;
  public currentBlog;
  public baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/blogs';

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) {
    console.log('blog http service constructor called');
  }

  private handleError(err:HttpErrorResponse){
    console.log("handle error http calls");
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message)

  }

  public getAllBlogs(): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/all');
    console.log(myResponse);
    return myResponse;

  }

  public getSingleBlogInformation(currentBlogId): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/view/' + currentBlogId);
    return myResponse;
  }

  public createBlog(blogData): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/create', blogData);
    return myResponse;

  }

  public deleteBlog(blogId): any {
    let data = {}
    let myResponse = this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/' + blogId + '/delete', blogId);
    return myResponse;

  }

  public editBlog(blogId, blogData): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.put(this.baseUrl + '/' + blogId + '/edit' , blogData);
    return myResponse;
  }
}
```

my nodejs **routes with controller for blog-view**

```
app.get(baseUrl+'/view/:blogId', (req, res) => {

    BlogModel.findOne({ 'blogId': req.params.blogId }, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(err)
        } else if (result == undefined || result == null || result == '') {
            console.log('No Blog Found')
            res.send("No Blog Found")
        } else {
            res.send(result)

        }
    })
});
```

**Below is a sample document object from which the frontend should render**

```
{
    "_id": "5e0e8ac6dcfc4e2008390cdf",
    "blogId": "XAY2Qlhb",
    "__v": 0,
    "lastModified": "2020-01-03T00:28:54.638Z",
    "created": "2020-01-03T00:28:54.638Z",
    "tags": [
        "english movies, action movies"
    ],
    "author": "Decardo",
    "category": "Hollywood custom",
    "isPublished": true,
    "views": 8,
    "bodyHtml": "<h1>Heading of the body</h1>\n<p>This is the first blog data getting uploaded n blog project</p>",
    "description": "long description>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",
    "title": "Blog Title 1 custom"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(data);` inside `this.blogHttpService.getSingleBlogInformation(myBlogId).subscribe` ?

Comment: when I'm hitting the api to get single blog the console is returning this:                  home component destroyed
blog-view.component.ts:21 view-blog constructor called
blog-view.component.ts:25 view-blog ngOnInIt called
blog-view.component.ts:27 XAY2Qlhb
blog-view.component.ts:31 {_id: "5e0e8ac6dcfc4e2008390cdf", blogId: "XAY2Qlhb", __v: 0, lastModified: "2020-01-03T00:28:54.638Z", created: "2020-01-03T00:28:54.638Z", …}

Comment: then I think `this.currentBlog = data["data"];` is not correct. It should be `this.currentBlog = data;`

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will first store a `Subscription` in `this.currentBlog`:

`this.currentBlog = this.blogHttpService.getSingleBlogInformation(myBlogId).subscribe(...)`

Then the subscription will be overwritten by `this.currentBlog = data["data"];`

`this.currentBlog =` is actually not needed there.
Not sure if that is the problem. At least it is not proper :)